# Can't start sql db in 11g through jdbc.Getting java sql exception

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;

public class Test {

static final String url2= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP 

(HOST=192.168.1.171)(PORT=5521))"+"(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = rdbms)))";

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

            OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();
           Properties prop = new Properties();
           prop.setProperty("user","system");
           prop.setProperty("password","manager");
           prop.setProperty("internal_logon","sysdba");
           prop.setProperty("prelim_auth","true");
           ds.setConnectionProperties(prop);
           ds.setURL(url2);
           OracleConnection conn = (OracleConnection)ds.getConnection();
           conn.startup(OracleConnection.DatabaseStartupMode.NO_RESTRICTION);
           conn.close();
    }
}
```

getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

**Cause:**
The listener received a request to establish a connection to a database or other service. The connect descriptor received by the listener specified a service name for a service (usually a database service) that either has not yet dynamically registered with the listener or has not been statically configured for the listener. This may be a temporary condition such as after the listener has started, but before the database instance has registered with the listener.

**Action:** 
- Wait a moment and try to connect a second time.

- Check which services are currently known by the listener by executing: lsnrctl services
- Check that the SERVICE_NAME parameter in the connect descriptor of the net service name used specifies a service known by the listener.
- If an easy connect naming connect identifier was used, check that the service name specified is a service known by the listener.
- Check for an event in the listener.log file.

Answer (score 0):

You must understand that when it comes to exceptions, many times JDBC simply serves as a wrapper to errors that occur at the DB side, 
or propagates driver specific (i.e - postgresql jdbc driver, oracle jdbc driver) specific errors. 
You should google the error and you will find what I believe is a clear explanation: 
http://ora-12514.ora-code.com/. 
If you see one of the suggestions there is to retry after a few seconds and reconnect again.